# Kick's store won't open

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Kick's shoe store started building 3 days ago. It still won't open. Every time I go on Main Street, It's still building. Has something happened, or does it take longer? If so, how much longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It should take 3 days. In any case, from the date you've posted this, I can only assume that it completed in all this time!